# Single classification neuron/perceptron in R

Tags: neural-network

I am looking for a package that provides a single neuron/perceptron for classification in R. So far I only found multi-layer perceptrons. Where can I find one?

Comment: Seems off topic to me, better chance on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Is this better for stats or datascience? I am not clear or the differences of those two.

Comment: The latter has only 1847 questions and is beta, while the first has 11600 that are tagged "R"... (Open question: is the second one really necessary ?)